# How to insert a different object with an array inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to test something in javascript with an array and object here is what I'm trying to do:

## CODE:

```js
    const data = [
      {
        name: "Order A",
        orderItems: [
          {
            qty: [2, 2, 2],
            products: [
              { name: "Product A" },
              { name: "Product B" },
              { name: "Product C" },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
    
    const dataName = data.map(({ name }) => {
      return name;
    });
    
    const product = data.map(({ orderItems }) => {
      return orderItems.map(({ qty, products }) => {
        return products.map(({ name }) => {
          return name + qty;
        });
      });
    });
    
    console.log(`This is ${dataName} with ${product}`);
```

I want it to return something like `A2`, `B2`, and `C2` but it returns something like `A2,2,2` `B2,2,2` `C2,2,2` I know I did something wrong. If you need anymore clarification please let me know.

Comment: When you do `name + qty` the `qty` variable is an entire array.... Also, your data object isn't great, your products array would be easier to deal with if it contained this type of object `{name: 'Product A', qty: 2}`

Comment: Yes, I had also think of a way like that `{name: 'Product A', qty: 2}` the one you are saying but I need a way to make it something like that. If possible could you make something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're concatenating the whole `qty` array. Pass the `products` array index  and concatenate the corresponding `qty` instead.

```
const product = data.map(({ orderItems }) => {
  return orderItems.map(({ qty, products }) => {
    return products.map(({ name }, i) => {
      return name + qty[i];
    });
  });
});

console.log(`This is ${dataName} with ${product}`);
```

*Output*

```
This is Order A with Product A2,Product B2,Product C2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this? Don't forget you've got an index as the second param of array methods, and i think - you just need to use it to solve your problem :)

```
 const ret = data.flatMap(({orderItems}) => orderItems).flatMap(({qty, products}) => {
    return qty.flatMap((quantity, index) => ({quantity, name: products[index].name}))
 });
ret.forEach(({name, quantity})=>console.log(name, quantity))
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering it also worked. :))